# How to declare a typed object with arbitrary keys?

Tags: typescript

In a `.d.ts` file, how do I define an object as having string keys and `T` values?

e.g.

```
declare var Game: {
    creeps: Object<string, Creep>; // not sure what syntax to use here
};

declare class Creep {
   // definition...
}
```

`Game.creeps` is an `object`, but I don't know what properties/keys it will have (they're defined at run time -- I'm using it like a dictionary), however, I do know that all its values will be `Creep`s.

My IDE says "Object is not generic" so I guess that syntax isn't quite right.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use an *index signature*:

```
declare var Game: {
    creeps: {[key:string]: Creep}
};
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Didn't know what to search for. Will accept in ~5min

Comment: This still [errors in VSCode](http://i.imgur.com/Sf3txDO.png). Is that a bug in VS Code or is there another way to say "any property is OK"?

Comment: You need to access it as a dictionary i.e. `creeps['key']` instead of `creeps.key`. If you know the key name then you should add it as a standard prop instead of using an index signagure

Comment: Aha! I didn't expect those behave differently. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 12):

basrat's answer still works fine but, in Typescript 2.1 or higher, there is a typing that looks more similar to what you originally thought might work:

```js
declare var Game: {
    creeps: Record<string, Creep>
};
```

There's no real difference, though I'd add that Typescript assumes that for any `K` value a `Record<K, V>` can produce a corresponding `V` value. For example:

```js
type Creep = {
    id: number;
}

function printIt(c: Creep) {
    console.log(c.id);
}

let game: Record<string, Creep> = {"test": {id: 0}};
printIt(thing["quest"]);
```

will compile - even with `strictNullChecks` - although it will definitely result in a run-time error. So you need to check index access yourself, and/or use the `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` flag as @mpen suggested.

Comment: There's a new flag in TS 4.1 that will treat all index signatures as optional if you want to get a warning for that. `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess`