# Assign Dynamic api reponse to typescript interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to typscript and nodejs.  I am trying to assign a response get it from restful api call to typescript interface. I dont want to use Object.keys or Obejct.values to get the required data but trying to use typescirpt interface for that .

Here is the response ,

```
// this is dynamic in nature
{ 
  return: [{ 
      'domain1.com': true, 
      'domaim2.com': true, 
      'domain3.com': true 
      }]
}
```

the domain name key value is not limited to 3 , it might be n . And the above response is not even json but thats what i am getting from the response.

I am using the following ts interface to assign the response .

```
 export interface ResponseString {
     Res: string;
 }

 export interface ServerRes {
         return: ResponseString[];
 }

try {
       data =  await getServerResponse();
   }
   catch (e) {
       console.error(e);
       throw new Error("Exception: failure ..");
   }
   try {
       const Servers: string[] = Object.keys(data.return[0]); // I want to use tyscrpit interface instread of object.keys to get the domains 

       for (const server of Servers) {
           // to be done
   }
   catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
   }
```

Please share your input on how to accomplish this .

[Update]

I am also getting other API responses that are something like below,

```
{ return: [ 
    { 'domainroot.com':'domain1.com' : ['some valu, 'some other value'] } 
]}
```

these responses are also dynamic but only key value changes but hte object does not change it would be like

```
{ ret: [ {'df':'df' : [ 'df', 'dfd']}]}
```

Thanks,

Comment: [return is a reserved keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords). Not a good idea to use for other stuff than actually "returning"

Comment: ok , changed to retval but I am not sure how i can map the {'key':true, 'key2',ture ......} to interface.

Comment: Why don't you want to use Object.keys? It's standard way to enumarate dynamic keys of object

Comment: I am Trying to make it structured by using interfaces everywhere .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to declare a typed object with arbitrary keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590284/how-to-declare-a-typed-object-with-arbitrary-keys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is type definitions

```
interface ServerResponse  {
  ['return']: { [k: string]: boolean }[]
};

let r: ServerResponse = { 'return':[ { 'domain1.com': true,'domaim2.com': true,'domain3.com': true } ] }
```

Anyway you have to use Objects.keys to enumerate servers

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will try this out.

Comment: You are right, somewhere we need to either use Object.keys or Object.values

Comment: The above code does not work well with the requirement but I understood that we had to use Object,keys or Object.values for dynamic responses that one cant be assigned to interfaces for now. So accepting this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an interface with a signature `string: boolean`

```
const data = {
  "retval": [{
    "domain1.com": true,
    "domaim2.com": false,
    "domain3.com": true
  }]
};

interface ServerStatusList {
  [key: string]: boolean;
}

const servers: ServerStatusList = data.retval[0];


for (let server in servers) { 
  console.log(`server ${server} : ${servers[server]}`);
}
```

[Try it in the Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20data%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%22retval%22%3A%20%5B%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22domain1.com%22%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22domaim2.com%22%3A%20false%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22domain3.com%22%3A%20true%0D%0A%20%20%7D%5D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ServerStatusList%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20servers%3A%20ServerStatusList%20%3D%20data.retval%5B0%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afor%20(let%20server%20in%20servers)%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20console.log(%60server%20%24%7Bserver%7D%20%3A%20%24%7Bservers%5Bserver%5D%7D%60)%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Thanks for the answer i will try this out.

Comment: I am getting compilation issues in typescript and also rest of the code gets response and those are also dynamic and bit slightly different from above example . In that case I opt /forced to use either Obejct.keys or Object.values , everything I have used in code is typed . In above example the data is not typed I think thats why i am getting errors while trying to port this example code.

Comment: Without the correct code in your question we can not see what can be wrong.

Comment: You code update does not make any sense. `{'df':'df' : [ 'df', 'dfd']}` is not a valid javascript object or JSON

Comment: Yes it is not a valid json or javascript object . Even the first example in question is also not a valid respose. some one made review of that from stackoverflow  and corrected it .