# Typescript Dynamic keys in Interface

Tags: typescript, interface

I have an API I'm working with that allows you to search for different games by platform. I'm trying to map out the appropriate interfaces for them, but the top level object key changes with each search type.

The response from the HTTP request gives me back...

```
ps4: {
  data: [{
    ...
  }]

OR...

xbox: {
  data: [{
    ...
  }]

OR...

switch: {
  data: [{
    ...
  }]
```

As you can see, the top level object changes with each type of HTTP request, but the data itself remains the same. How do you map out an interface for that key to change dynamically? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to declare a typed object with arbitrary keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590284/how-to-declare-a-typed-object-with-arbitrary-keys)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define an interface for it like this:

```
interface Response {
  [key: string]: {
    data: Object[]
  }
}
```

OR to be more explicit you can define a type with all the possible keys

```
type TKeys 'ps4' |'xbox' | 'switch';

type Response = {
  [key in TKeys]: {
    data: Object[]
  }
}
```

You can also consider using an `enum` type like this

```
enum Platforms {
 ps4 = 'ps4',
 xbox = 'xbox',
 switch = 'switch'
}

type Response = {
  [key in Platforms]: {
    data: Object[];
  };
};
```

Comment: Your second suggestion is not valid TypeScript.

Comment: Yes, I just updated it. I was copy/pasting @jcalz

Comment: So you’re suggesting that it should require all 3 keys?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, and he could specify more platforms, so the type is more explicit as opposed to just using string.

Comment: It doesn't seem to like that. I'm getting an error for "An index signature parameter type cannot be a union type consider using a mapped object type instead"

Comment: Is this for the second options @ACDev

Comment: Consider using an enum type. See my updated answer on how to do that @ACDev

Comment: Cool! Go ahead and accept the answer as well @ACDev

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work:

```
interface Data {
    data: object[];
}

interface Response {
    [x: string]: Data
}
```

Note that I've used `object` intentionally instead of `Object` as it suits your case better. More on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49464634/difference-between-object-and-object-in-typescript)

Comment: Lmaoo, you literally just copied the first suggestion in my answer and modified it, by creating a second interface.

Comment: Did not see your answer while I was writing mine. My apologies if it appears that way. @fortunee
I'd have commented otherwise

Comment: Sorry dude, I believe you and I didn't mean to sound like you actually copied me.

Comment: No worries. In the friendly spirit, I'll upvote your answer. Cheers mate !! @fortunee

Comment: Yours too my friend!